# DB Error: no such field Died during callApi - Error with civicrm_status_pref table

Tags: wordpress, error

**System:**
WordPress 5.3.2, CiviCRM 5.20.2, PHP 7.1.33

**Problem:**
Since 1/1/2020 at 12:00am, every time our cron job runs on the hour I get an email notification that says

DB Error: no such field
Died during callApi

In looking at the error log (shown below), the error is in an UPDATE statement on the civicrm_status_pref table, saying that the is_active field doesn't exist. But it does:

[image: Structure of civicrm_status_prefs]

I am not getting any other errors. System Status says that I'm a little behind with the PHP version and CiviCRM (but the error has persisted through one civi update). All extensions are up to date. And as near as I can tell, everything in CiviCRM is working fine.

What am I missing? Why am I getting this error? Thanks!

Error Log:

```
Feb 17 16:00:02  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
    (
        [callback] => Array
            (
                [0] => CRM_Core_Error
                [1] => exceptionHandler
            )

        [code] => -19
        [message] => DB Error: no such field
        [mode] => 16
        [debug_info] => UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ignore_severity = 0 , check_info = '1581987602' , is_active = 1   WHERE (  civicrm_status_pref.id = 1 )   [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_active' in 'field list']
        [type] => DB_Error
        [user_info] => UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ignore_severity = 0 , check_info = '1581987602' , is_active = 1   WHERE (  civicrm_status_pref.id = 1 )   [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_active' in 'field list']
        [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ignore_severity = 0 , check_info = '1581987602' , is_active = 1   WHERE (  civicrm_status_pref.id = 1 )   [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_active' in 'field list']"]
    )


    Feb 17 16:00:02  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
    #1 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))
    #2 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(987): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...")
    #3 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...")
    #4 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
    #5 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1920): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
    #6 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'is_active' in 'field list'")
    #7 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
    #8 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1229): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...")
    #9 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2416): DB_common->query("UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...")
    #10 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1318): DB_DataObject->_query("UPDATE  civicrm_status_pref  SET domain_id = 1 , name = 'checkLastCron' , ign...")
    #11 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(560): DB_DataObject->update()
    #12 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/StatusPreference.php(86): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
    #13 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(93): CRM_Core_BAO_StatusPreference::create((Array:3))
    #14 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(134): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE)
    #15 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(101): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:2))
    #16 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(168): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
    #17 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(99): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9))
    #18 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "execute", (Array:2), NULL)
    #19 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php(122): civicrm_api("Job", "execute", (Array:2))
    #20 /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php(32): civicrm_cli->callApi()
    #21 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO you have DB logging turned on? If so turn it off & back on again - the log_civicrm_status_pref table might be missing the field

Comment: I do indeed have logging turned on. Turning it off and back on didn't do anything, but manually adding the field to log_civicrm_status_pref seems to have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same, the table was missing, I added it using

https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/ac3d5bbc90712348d79a8d56bdd0b5ca

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_status_pref` (


     `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT 'Unique Status Preference ID',
     `domain_id` int unsigned NOT NULL   COMMENT 'Which Domain is this Status Preference for',
     `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL   COMMENT 'Name of the status check this preference references.',
     `hush_until` date   DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'expires ignore_severity.  NULL never hushes.',
     `ignore_severity` int unsigned   DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'Hush messages up to and including this severity.',
     `prefs` varchar(255)    COMMENT 'These settings are per-check, and can\'t be compared across checks.',
     `check_info` varchar(255)    COMMENT 'These values are per-check, and can\'t be compared across checks.' 
,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 
    ,     INDEX `UI_status_pref_name`(
        name
  )
  
,          CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_status_pref_domain_id FOREIGN KEY (`domain_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_domain`(`id`)   
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  ;
```

and disabling the foreign key check.